# How would I hide the control points on a matplotlib Path constructed with CURVE3 or CURVE4

Tags: python, matplotlib, bezier, curve

This [example of creating a bezier curve](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/advanced/path_tutorial.html#bezier-example) does just what it says on the tin.  What I can't figure out is how to just show the curve without the control points.  I've looked at other examples -- some show the control point data, some don't, and I have not been able to figure out why.  Suggestions gratefully received.

[image: bezier curves]

Comment: Why don't you comment out from  `# ax.text(0.85, -0.05, 'P3')` to ?`# xs, ys = zip(*verts)` ?

Comment: Because I was thinking that particular plot defined the axes and stupidity knows no bounds.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These 2 lines are responsible for making the control points:

```
xs, ys = zip(*verts)
ax.plot(xs, ys, 'x--', lw=2, color='black', ms=10)
```

So then, if you delete these lines of code, you will be able to get a clear curve with no control points and trajectory guidance. 
 
These other four lines are the labels near the points:

```
ax.text(-0.05, -0.05, 'P0')
ax.text(0.15, 1.05, 'P1')
ax.text(1.05, 0.85, 'P2')
ax.text(0.85, -0.05, 'P3')
```

I think you would like to delete them too, in order to maintain only the Bézier curve.